# Derivation of Joint discrete entropy to Conditional Entropy

Tags: probability-theory, entropy

I am trying to prove this

$$H(X,Y)=H(X)+H(Y|X)$$

However, I am stuck on a certain part.

$$\begin{align}
  & -\sum\limits_{x}{\sum\limits_{y}{p(X,Y)\log (p(X,Y))}} \\ 
 & =-\sum\limits_{x}{\sum\limits_{y}{p(X)p(Y|X)\log (p(X)p(Y|X))}} \\ 
 & =-\sum\limits_{x}{\sum\limits_{y}{p(X)p(Y|X)(\log (p(X))+log(p(Y|X)))}} \\ 
 & =-\sum\limits_{x}{\sum\limits_{y}{p(X)p(Y|X)\log (p(X))-\sum\limits_{x}{\sum\limits_{y}{p(X)p(Y|X)log(p(Y|X))}}}} \\ 
\end{align}
$$

Let's call first summation $a$ and second summation $b$. I can easily convert $b$ to $H(Y|X)$ as follows.

$$\begin{align}
  & -\sum\limits_{x}{\sum\limits_{y}{p(X=x)p(Y=y|X=x)log(p(Y=y|X=x))}} \\ 
 & =-\sum\limits_{x}{p(X=x)\sum\limits_{y}{p(Y=y|X=x)log(p(Y=y|X=x))}} \\ 
 & =\sum\limits_{x}{p(X=x)H(Y|X=x)} \\ 
 & =H(Y|X) \\ 
\end{align}$$

But for $a$ I cannot reduce it to $H(X)$

$$\begin{align}
  & -\sum\limits_{x}{\sum\limits_{y}{p(X=x)p(Y=y|X=x)log(p(X=x))}} \\ 
 & =-\sum\limits_{x}{p(X=x)log(p(X=x))\sum\limits_{y}{p(Y=y|X=x)}} \\ 
\end{align}
$$

I am stuck here. What am I missing?

Comment: You are literally there; for a fixed x, when you sum over all y, what is that sum?

Comment: Since this is information theory; let me give you a more coding theory example: given that I sent a 1 (X = 1), and my possible outputs (domain of Y) are 1,2, or 3, what is P(Y = 1 | X = 1) + P(Y = 2 | X = 1) + P(Y = 3 | X =1) (i.e. probability I receive either 1, 2, or 3 (where obviously they are all disjoint)

Comment: Can you elaborate more? Why is it that sum over y is equal to 1 for a fixed x? I am not too familiar with information theory and I was thinking it w.r.t. simple discrete distribution like rolling two die and in that case over fixed x the sum is not 1.

Comment: Sum is 1: in terms of dice, let me give you an example: let your experiment be a dice roll; X be 0 if dice roll is even, 1 if not, and let Y be the output. Now, conditioned on X = 0, if you sum over all Y, you get P(Y = 1 | X = 0) + P(Y = 2 | X = 0) + P(Y = 3 | X = 0) + P(Y = 4 | X = 0) + P(Y = 5 | X = 0) + P(Y = 6 | X = 0) = 0 + 1/3 + 0 + 1/3 + 0 + 1/3 = 1. Basically, regardless of what X is, one of the outcomes must have happened, right? Sum being 1 reflects that.

Comment: So, we are only dealing with binary outcomes??

Comment: No; regarless of what X is (you could have looked numbers with remainders 0,1,2 after being divided by 3); that sum over Y is always 1. Do you know why $\sum_x p(X = x)$ = 1?

Comment: Not true, here is an example where I roll two die. P(Y = 1 | X = 1) + P(Y = 2 | X = 1) + P(Y = 3 | X = 1) + P(Y = 4 | X = 1) + P(Y = 5 | X = 1) + P(Y = 6 | X = 1) = 1/36 + 1/36 + 1/36 + 1/36 + 1/36 + 1/36 = 1/6 not 1. P(Y | X) is always 1/6.

Comment: You are mistaking conditional distribution with joint distribution... P(Y = 1 | X = 1) = 1/6 not 1/36... Have you taken introduction to probability? It will immensely help you studying information theory.

Comment: Oops..my bad. Got it now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68596/discussion-between-e-a-and-kay-yak).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is given in the chat above; the missing final step is that the final summation with the conditional expectation sums up to 1.